# How does one run Unity 3D (the full free version) in Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, wine, games, 3d

How  does one install Unity 3D (the full free version) on Ubuntu?

I have tried to run the program through Wine 64-bit, and I get this message every time:

> Error initializing license system. Please contact support@unity3D.com

Is there any way to get past this. Or better yet, is there any way to get Wine to run the program?

Comment: I found this video that seems to have what you are looking for. This guy says you have to use and create a 32 bit library for it (common problem on 64 bit systems using emu and virtlike environments.) You don't have to know what you are doing to make the terminal work, just type whatever command or copy/paste and press enter :)

Comment: Can you post a link to this video for me, please? I'm taking whatever I can get at this point.

Comment: that might help, right? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa26vR51PkQ and check out this page as well specific to 14.04 http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity3d-on-linux-with-wine-support-thread.211059/page-6

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, mchid. I will try to follow the video tomorrow and I'll leave the results here. :)

Comment: I watched the video and attempted the steps. Upon reaching the part when I needed to install fonts, it froze at "eurofixi.exe" and didn't do anything. Along with that, I need to convert Wine to 32-bit, but the *terminal* steps did not work. The third command gave me this message: "wine: invalid directory prefix32 in WINEPREFIX: not an absolute path". Just... WHAT?! I'm sorry, but I'm sick of the PROBLEMS that Linux gives. I'm seriously considering switching to Windows if this crap keeps happening...

Comment: Instructions for installing the fonts are on http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity3d-on-linux-with-wine-support-thread.211059/page-6 . Also, it may be easier for you to install a separate i386 ubuntu next to your current OS to work with 32 because multiarch can be a headache anyways.